# How to Solve ambiguous in clr based c++?

Tags: c#, c++11, visual-c++

I am a .net developer. i am new to c++ code.

In native c++ project i am changed for the clr based for accessing c#. i am  writing wrapper of c++ managed clr code.I was build the code it's throw the error

> "ambiguous for IServiceProvider"

Error Image:-

[image]

In this IServiceProvider is include in native headers and managed clr namespaces. How can i solve this problem.

I was checking internet for this problem. i am not able to find the solution. they given solution not worked for me.

pls anyone know share the knowledge.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](https://qualapps.blogspot.jp/2008/07/using-atlstrh-in-managed-project.html), the problem is caused by both the Microsoft SDK and mscorlib having definitions for `IServiceProvider`.

The solution is simple:

> The solution is to take the #include file that caused the problem and make sure it is placed before any "using namespace" statement. In my case, that meant moving #include near the top of stdafx.h.